# В чем разница между Scanner scanner и Scanner console в Java?

Tags: java

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
```

/

```
Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
```

Comment: Ни в чём, название переменной ни на что не влияет

Comment: Сканер это обертка над потоком со своими плюшками вот и все, не понимаю ваш вопрос.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ни в чем, scanner и console это название.
Шаблон для создания сканера
`Scanner название = new Scanner(System.in);`

Answer (score 3):

Scanner **scanner** = new Scanner(System.in);

Слово, выделенное жирным — это название переменной. Далее в коде вы будете обращаться к переменной по тому имени, которое дали ей при создании. Соответственно, если вы назвали её `scanner`, то далее вы будете обращаться к ней по имени `scanner`, а если назвали `console` — по имени `console`